# Send raw POST request with OkHttp 3

Tags: java, http, okhttp

To send a POST request with OkHttp I've seen they use FormBody.Builder, but that requires me to manually input each name and value for the POST data. Is there a way to create a RequestBody with a single String with the POST data? For example, instead of

```
FormBody.Builder bodyBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();

bodyBuilder.add("name", "value");
bodyBuilder.add("name2", "value2");
```

...just doing

```
bodyBuilder.add("name=value&name2=value2");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean by "inputting it manually"? You put it once in your source code and that's it?

Comment: Have you tried `RequestBody.create(MediaType contentType, String content)`? Pass the contentType and the content as a string.

Comment: Yeah but the project I'm working on is based on parsing POST data and sending a number of requests. And well, converting the raw data into a Map each time would cost performance

Comment: rcorreia yep I did, and it doesn't send any data for some reason... Does the contentType matter though?

Comment: @JohnRock Try create this variable `public static final MediaType FORM = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");`. Pass the FORM variable as contentType.

Comment: Doesn't work. My code:

        ```MediaType form = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");

        okhttp3.Request.Builder requestBuilder = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(RequestBody.create(form, postData));```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), "key1=value1&key2=value2");

Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url(url)
.post(body)
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, using `RequestBuilder`

```
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body) // here you put your body
      .build();
```

But URL encoding and other related stuff will be on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Create a MediaType variable named FORM:

```
public static final MediaType FORM = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");
```

Create a RequestBody using the FORM variable and your unparsed params (String):

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(FORM, params);
```

Post the full requestBody variable.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .post(requestBody)
    .build();
```

Comment: For some reason it won't send the post data this way

Comment: Are you seeing the request on the server side? Can you post the full request?

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply do this with the latest version:

```kotlin
val reqBody = "foo=bar"
val request = Request.Builder().post(reqBody.toRequestBody()).build()
```